# What can be done to improve IHTMLDOMAttribute cast performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, com-interop, mshtml

I'm trying to sanitize/modify the html tree by building the mshtml DOM and then traversing it.
The problem is, it takes a very long time to do so, up to 3-4 seconds for a standart twitter newsletter or something on par with that.

After the profiling session i was able to pinpoint the hotspot:

```
private void AddAttributes(IHTMLDOMNode node)
{
        string nodeName = node.nodeName;
        var attributes = (IHTMLAttributeCollection) node.attributes;
        int length = attributes.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            //problem line
            IHTMLDOMAttribute attribute = attributes.item(i) as IHTMLDOMAttribute;

            string attributeName = attribute.nodeName;

            //do some work
            ...
        }
}
```

Casting to IHTMLDOMAttribute is taking 75% percent of the time (in comparison, whole DOM creation takes only ~3%)

Profiler's output for AddAttributes:
Function body: 0.3%
Called functions:
   DoCLRToCOMCall: 41.5%
   JITutil_ChkCastAny: 27.2%
   ?InterfaceMarshaler_ConvertToManaged...: 10%

What can i do to improve the performance in this case?

I've been here: [HTML Traversal is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666302/html-traversal-is-very-slow), it looks similar, but we are stuck with .NET 3.5, so dynamics are out of question. There are several other reports about similar problems over the [internet](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/352596-mshtml-asp-net-web-application-slow), but there's no clear answer, only hints on marshalling problems.

*HTML Agility Pack, while being much faster, is incapable of parsing CSS attributes, which is crucial for us.*

Comment: *Try* moving all code in JavaScript - if slowness comes because of COM/C# interop you may get better performance...

Comment: We need to parse html from the mails, entire project is c#-based. 
It is expected to have some kind of performance loss due to the interop, but that's too much for expected behaviour.

Comment: Obviously was unclear suggestion - try to move code that deals with changing/cleaning HTML/CSS over to JavaScript - keep whatever browser hosting in C# indeed.

Comment: Try [`TreeWalker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if you do any better.

Comment: Well, we did  something close to it. Ended up transferring problematic class to the c++ helper library, which essentially reduced marshalling to the exchange of strings. Still it would be nice to know if there could be an alternative answer.